# Journey builder issue with Contact Data

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, custom-object, marketing-cloud-connect

There is an issue with my Journey in Marketing Cloud instance.
There are 2 actions: we send SMS messages via that journey and log the answers to these SMS in Salesforce in 24h.

The journey runs once an hour and queries all the events where start date is in 47.5-48.5h from the run time. For each event it sends SMS to the related contact with a question if they confirm their attendance. We need these SMS messages to be visible in Salesforce, so the next step of the journey is object activity that creates SMS record in Salesforce (relates it to the respective Contact and Event). Then, 24h later, journey checks if the contact confirmed their presence. If yes, object activity creates a record with the reply in Salesforce (again, the record is related to the respective Contact and Event).

In case there is only 1 event for the contact in the data extension, everything works perfectly.

But once contact registered for the second event, object activity takes the very first event of this contact and relates all SMS replies to it (and not for the second event as we expect).

The action (object activity) that creates record in Salesforce works as expected for most of the cases except for the scenario when there are 2 messages were sent to the same Contact in different period of time (so 2 same contactID, but related EventIDs are different). We use ‘contact data’ instead of 'journey data' due to the fact that we need to get an SMS-reply data from the extension.

Here is the example:

| Contact ID | Event ID |
| --- | --- |
| ContactId 1 | Event 1 |
| ContactId 1 | Event 2 |

For the first time it works as expected and the record in Salesforce is created with the relevant data (Contact 1, Event 1).

For the second time the data is incorrect.

**Expected result**: Contact 1, Event 2

**Actual result**: Contact 1, Event 1

Does anyone has ideas how that can be fixed?

Comment: you'll need to look at attribute to attribute comparsion

Comment: Are you sure that we can do attribute to attribute comparsion in 'object activity' element? We can only select fields there.

Comment: Your issue appears to be related to the difference between 'journey data' and 'contact data'. Since you use 'contact data', you always get the most recent Event ID. I may need more details to help further. Like more details on what Obj activity is doing, how you are testing with the same contact entering journey etc

Comment: @vijaya-kapadam I updated the description, please check it

Comment: @SlavikKharkovskiy, Thanks for those details; few more queries 
Where and how are you storing and using SMS replies in the journey? 
You can ensure below.
1. Make sure entry DE has identified that is a combination of (Contact ID, Event ID & TimeStamp)
2. Don't use "contact data" to create records in Salesforce; use "journey data" for the SMS replies. Pass the data from the journey context to the "object activity" to create records in CRM. 
3. Double-check the settings of the "object activity", configured to retrieve and relate the SMS replies to the respective Event record